# Conditionally hiding and showing block and links

Tags: layout, blocks, controllers, toplinks, layout-update

I am working on an application for which i have two types of user in Magento system. Each user can login and reach to their Dashboard. On the user Dashboard depending on what kind of user is logged in, I want to show/hide blocks from layout.

With understanding i have so far, I was able to reach a solution. Where I am adding blocks for both the users in layout update handler and then conditionally based on what kind of user is logged in, I am removing blocks not required for that particular user from layout.

Even though this solution works but i think this isn't the right approach to do the things, as every time i create new controller action I need to put this check and accordingly modify layout.

What can be a better approach to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## two layout handle

Add your own layout handle which maps to the customer-type. So you can add the blocks based on the type.

To do this, [follow the link to inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-layout-update-handles/).

TL;DR

create observer listening on `inchoo_controller_action_layout_load_before`

```
class Inchoo_LayoutHandle_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionLayoutLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $layout Mage_Core_Model_Layout */
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        $type = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getType();
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_' . $type);
    }
}
```